# Space Delimited 'Export To Text' Excel Macro Issue

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have the below **vba macro** to Export the selected cells into a text file.  The problem seems to be the delimiter.

I need everything to be in an exact position.  I have each column's width set to the correct width(*9 for 9 like SSN*) and I have the cells font as Courier New(*9pt*) in an Excel Sheet.

When I run this it comes out **REALLY** close to what I need but it doesn't seem to deal with the columns that are just a single space in width.

I will put the **WHOLE** method (*and accompanying function*) at the bottom for reference but first I'd like to post the portion **I THINK** is where I need to focus on.  I just don't know in what way...

This is where **I believe** my issue is(delimiter is set to `delimiter = ""` -->

```
' Loop through every cell, from left to right and top to bottom.
  For RowNum = 1 To TotalRows
     For ColNum = 1 To TotalCols
        With Selection.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
        Dim ColWidth As Integer
        ColWidth = Application.RoundUp(.ColumnWidth, 0)
        ' Store the current cells contents to a variable.
        Select Case .HorizontalAlignment
           Case xlRight
              CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text))) & .Text
           Case xlCenter
              CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)) / 2) & .Text & _
                         Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)) / 2)
           Case Else
              CellText = .Text & Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)))
        End Select
        End With


' Write the contents to the file.
   ' With or without quotation marks around the cell information.
            Select Case quotes
               Case vbYes
                  CellText = Chr(34) & CellText & Chr(34) & delimiter
               Case vbNo
                  CellText = CellText & delimiter
            End Select
            Print #FNum, CellText;

   ' Update the status bar with the progress.
            Application.StatusBar = Format((((RowNum - 1) * TotalCols) _
               + ColNum) / (TotalRows * TotalCols), "0%") & " Completed."

   ' Loop to the next column.
         Next ColNum
   ' Add a linefeed character at the end of each row.
         If RowNum <> TotalRows Then Print #FNum, ""
   ' Loop to the next row.
      Next RowNum
```

---

This is the **WHOLE SHEBANG**!  For reference the original is [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249885).

```
Sub ExportText()
'
' ExportText Macro
'
Dim delimiter As String
   Dim quotes As Integer
   Dim Returned As String


  delimiter = ""

  quotes = MsgBox("Surround Cell Information with Quotes?", vbYesNo)



' Call the WriteFile function passing the delimiter and quotes options.
      Returned = WriteFile(delimiter, quotes)

   ' Print a message box indicating if the process was completed.
      Select Case Returned
         Case "Canceled"
            MsgBox "The export operation was canceled."
         Case "Exported"
            MsgBox "The information was exported."
      End Select

   End Sub

   '-------------------------------------------------------------------

   Function WriteFile(delimiter As String, quotes As Integer) As String

   ' Dimension variables to be used in this function.
   Dim CurFile As String
   Dim SaveFileName
   Dim CellText As String
   Dim RowNum As Integer
   Dim ColNum As Integer
   Dim FNum As Integer
   Dim TotalRows As Double
   Dim TotalCols As Double


   ' Show Save As dialog box with the .TXT file name as the default.
   ' Test to see what kind of system this macro is being run on.
   If Left(Application.OperatingSystem, 3) = "Win" Then
      SaveFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(CurFile, _
      "Text Delimited (*.txt), *.txt", , "Text Delimited Exporter")
   Else
       SaveFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(CurFile, _
      "TEXT", , "Text Delimited Exporter")
   End If

   ' Check to see if Cancel was clicked.
      If SaveFileName = False Then
         WriteFile = "Canceled"
         Exit Function
      End If
   ' Obtain the next free file number.
      FNum = FreeFile()

   ' Open the selected file name for data output.
      Open SaveFileName For Output As #FNum

   ' Store the total number of rows and columns to variables.
      TotalRows = Selection.Rows.Count
      TotalCols = Selection.Columns.Count

   ' Loop through every cell, from left to right and top to bottom.
      For RowNum = 1 To TotalRows
         For ColNum = 1 To TotalCols
            With Selection.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
            Dim ColWidth As Integer
            ColWidth = Application.RoundUp(.ColumnWidth, 0)
            ' Store the current cells contents to a variable.
            Select Case .HorizontalAlignment
               Case xlRight
                  CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text))) & .Text
               Case xlCenter
                  CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)) / 2) & .Text & _
                             Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)) / 2)
               Case Else
                  CellText = .Text & Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)))
            End Select
            End With
   ' Write the contents to the file.
   ' With or without quotation marks around the cell information.
            Select Case quotes
               Case vbYes
                  CellText = Chr(34) & CellText & Chr(34) & delimiter
               Case vbNo
                  CellText = CellText & delimiter
            End Select
            Print #FNum, CellText;

   ' Update the status bar with the progress.
            Application.StatusBar = Format((((RowNum - 1) * TotalCols) _
               + ColNum) / (TotalRows * TotalCols), "0%") & " Completed."

   ' Loop to the next column.
         Next ColNum
   ' Add a linefeed character at the end of each row.
         If RowNum <> TotalRows Then Print #FNum, ""
   ' Loop to the next row.
      Next RowNum

   ' Close the .prn file.
      Close #FNum

   ' Reset the status bar.
      Application.StatusBar = False
      WriteFile = "Exported"
   End Function
```

---

### Further Discoveries

I discovered that there is something wrong with `Case xlCenter` below.  It's Friday and I haven't been able to wrap my head around it yet but whatever it is doing in that `case` was removing the " ".  I verified this by setting all columns to Left Justified so that the `Case Else` would be used instead and VIOLA!  My space remained.  I would like to understand why but in the end it is A) working and B) e.James's solution looks better anyway.

Thanks for the help.

```
Dim ColWidth As Integer
        ColWidth = Application.RoundUp(.ColumnWidth, 0)
        ' Store the current cells contents to a variable.
        Select Case .HorizontalAlignment
           Case xlRight
              CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text))) & .Text
           Case xlCenter
              CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)) / 2) & .Text & _
                         Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)) / 2)
           Case Else
              CellText = .Text & Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)))
        End Select
```

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information about the failure mode? What kind of output do you see now, and what kind of output do you expect to see?

Comment: I'll try.  I can't show the file as it has sensitive info on it.  The whole export should be 360 "positions" wide.  Out of 400 records about 15 where "wider" then 360 by a position or 2.  Position 10 (second column) is 1 and blank.  That was missing on ALL rows.  The 15 that were too wide were all originating with the same column (Street Address Position 186-210)

Comment: I think I see the problem with your centering code. Imagine that the column width is set to 20, and the text in that column is "hello". Then your code will put either 7 or 8 spaces on either side of the text (depending on how 15/2 is rounded off), and this will cause your total lenght to be either 19 or 21, but certainly not 20!

Comment: I'll add some code in my answer to provide a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem stems from your use of the column width as the number of characters to use. When I set a column width to 1.0 in Excel, any *numbers* displayed in that column simply disappear, and VBA shows that the `.Text` property for those cells is "", which makes sense, since the `.Text` property gives you the exact text that is visible in Excel.

Now, you have a couple of options here:

1. Use the `.Value` property instead of the `.Text` property. The downside of this approach is that it will discard any number formatting that you have applied in the spreadsheet (I'm not sure if this is a problem in your case)
2. Instead of using the column widths, place a row of values at the top of your spreadsheet (in row 1) to indicate the appropriate width for each column, then use those values in your VBA code instead of the column width. Then, you can make your columns a little bit wider in Excel (so that the text displays properly)

I would probably go with #2 but, of course, I don't know much about your setup, so I can't say for sure.

**edit:** The following workaround may do the trick. I modified your code to make use the `Value` and `NumberFormat` properties of each cell, instead of using the `.Text` property. This should take care of the problems with one-character wide cells.

```
With Selection.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
Dim ColWidth As Integer
ColWidth = Application.RoundUp(.ColumnWidth, 0)
'// Store the current cells contents to a variable.'
If (.NumberFormat = "General") Then
    CellText = .Text
Else
    CellText = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(.NumberFormat, .value)
End If
Select Case .HorizontalAlignment
  Case xlRight
    CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(CellText))) & CellText
  Case xlCenter
    CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(CellText)) / 2) & CellText & _
               Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(CellText)) / 2)
  Case Else
    CellText = CellText & Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(CellText)))
End Select
End With
```

**update:** to take care of the centering problem, I would do the following:

```
Case xlCenter
  CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(CellText)) / 2) & CellText
  CellText = CellText & Space(ColWidth - len(CellText))
```

This way, the padding on the right side of the text will automatically cover the remaining space.

Comment: e.James - Thanks for the help.  In looking at this I think I will change mine to this as well.  As a point of interest though see my edit for what I discovered was causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just saving it as space delimited? My understanding is it will treat column width as # of spaces, but haven't tried all scenarios. Doing this with Excel 2007 seems to work for me, or I don't understand enough of your issue. I did try with a column with width=1 and it rendered that as 1 space in the resulting text file.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Book1.prn", FileFormat:= _
    xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: That would work very well if I didn't have more then 240 characters on 1 line.  Here is a Microsoft quote on it...

"This behavior occurs because, by design, Formatted Text (Space Delimited) (.prn) files have a limit of 240 characters per line."
SOURCE -->http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249885#appliesto